# capturar elemeto id de un array javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Tengo este array en javascript y quiero elejir la propiedad "id" del elemento prenda que es un campo input para asi poder asir la peticion ajax y consultar con la hoja php.

**detalle de la salida**

```
function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,articulo,precio_venta)
  {
    var cantidad=1;
    var descuento=0;
    var prenda='';

    if (idarticulo!="")
    {
        var subtotal=cantidad*precio_venta;
        var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="prenda'+cont+'" name="prenda[]">'+prenda+' <button type="button" onclick="revisarDespacho('+document.getElementById('prenda'+cont+).value()+','+idarticulo+')" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="descuento[]" value="'+descuento+'"></td>'+
        '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
        '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubototales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
        '</tr>';
        cont++;
        detalles=detalles+1;
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
        modificarSubototales();
        //document.getElementById("prenda[]").onchange = function() {revisarDespacho(idarticulo)}
        console.log (idarticulo)
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
    }
  }
```

**peticion ajax:**

```
    function revisarDespacho(prenda,idventa)
{       
            $.post("../ajax/despacho.php?op=consultar", {prenda, idventa}, function(data){
                bootbox.alert(data);
                //tabla.ajax.reload();
                console.log(data);
                console.log(prenda,idventa);
            }); 
}
```

**requerimiento** al utilizar el evento onclick no me captura el document.getElementById('prenda'+cont+).value() que es el id del input prenda con su contador de filas, agradezco su valiosa colaboracion es algo importante para mi y no se como resolverlo

Comment: Atento con esta linea amigo , <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="prenda'+cont+'" name="prenda[]"> recuerda que si lees el value de un input cuando lo generes debes integrearlo en tu código  --- <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="prenda'+cont+'" name="prenda[]" value="tu valor">

Comment: amigo estuvo bien esa pero aun me arroja error de ')' en... document.getElementById('prenda'+cont+).value()... y ya revise pero no encuentro la solucion

Answer (score 0):

Dices que te da error ')' en

```
document.getElementById('prenda'+cont+).value()
```

si te fijas tienes un error de sintaxis en ('prenda'+cont+) o bien añades dos comillas después del '+' o quitas el '+'

Resultado:

```
document.getElementById('prenda'+cont).value()
```

Answer (score 0):

Resumiendo: tienes una tabla, y en esa tabla filas, y cada fila tiene asociado un índice `indexFila` y un `idArticulo` (tú le pusiste `cont` en vez de `indexFila` pero me tomaré esa licencia), con los cuales vas armando el name o el id de distintos inputs/controles que se dibujan en la fila.

La tercera columna tiene un campo de texto con id `prenda<indexFila>` o sea tendrás prenda1, prenda2, prenda3, etc. Y tiene un botón cuyo click llama a una funcion *revisarDespacho* que se ejecutará tomando como argumentos el valor del mentado campo de texto y el `idArticulo` asociado a la fila. Supongamos que es la fila 7 y el artículo 3, lo que insertas tiene en simple la forma

```
'<input type="text" id="prenda7" name="prenda[]">'+
'<button type="button" onclick="revisarDespacho('+document.getElementById('prenda7').value()+','+3+')"></button>'
```

Fíjate en la declaración de este handler:

```
onclick="revisarDespacho('+document.getElementById('prenda7').value()+','+3+')"
```

Está generando dos problemas: primero, *getElementById* retorna un [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), de entre los cuales un input no tiene un método `value` como jQuery sino un atributo `value`

```
 console.log( document.getElementById('prenda7').value() ); // mal
 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function

 console.log( document.getElementById('prenda7').value ); // bien
```

**segundo y más importante**, estás concatenando en el html el valor del input `prenda7` (que todavía no existe) y no una referencia textual. Dado que `document.getElementById('prenda7')` es null y null no tiene un atributo `value` debieras estar viendo un error en tu consola.

El handler debiera ser:

```
onclick="revisarDespacho(document.getElementById('prenda7').value, 3)"
```

Como gran parte de la confusión te está pasando por la mezcla de comillas dobles y simples, te recomiendo familiarizarte con el uso de [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) que te permite usar comillas dobles y simples sin escapar, saltos de línea e interpolación de variables y fórmulas. En esa celda, por ejemplo, teniendo `prenda` (hoy vacío), `indexFila` y un `idProducto`, se escribiría como

```
let celda = `<td>
    <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="prenda${indexFila}" name="prenda[]">${prenda} 
    <button type="button" onclick="revisarDespacho(document.getElementById('prenda${indexFila}').value,${idarticulo})" class="btn btn-info"> 
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> 
    </button>
</td>`;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando en donde separé las modificaciones al dom (añadir `tr` y a cada `tr` sus `td`) de la función que genera las celdas propiamente tales, las cuales de paso manejé como array para romper en piezas manejables el texto tan extenso.

```js
let cont = 0,
  detalles = 0;
const tabla = document.querySelector('#detalles');

function getCeldas(idarticulo, articulo, precio_venta, indexFila, cantidad = 1) {
  let descuento = 0,
    prenda = '',
    subtotal = cantidad * precio_venta;

  return [`<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle(${indexFila})">X</button>
  </td>`,
    `<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="${idarticulo}">${articulo}
    </td>`,
    `<td>
    <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="prenda${indexFila}" name="prenda[]" value="ejemplo ${indexFila}" >${prenda} 
        <button type="button" onclick="revisarDespacho(document.getElementById('prenda${indexFila}').value,${idarticulo})" class="btn btn-info"> 
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> 
        </button>
    </td>`,
    `<td class="numeric">
    <input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="${cantidad}"></td>`,
    `<td class="numeric">
    <input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="${precio_venta}"></td>`,
    `<td class="numeric">
    <input type="number" name="descuento[]" value="${descuento}">
    </td>`,
    `<td>
    <span name="subtotal" id="subtotal${indexFila}">${subtotal}</span>
    </td>`,
    `<td>
    <button type="button" onclick="modificarSubototales()" class="btn btn-info">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
    </td>`
  ];
}

function revisarDespacho(prendas, idArticulo) {
  console.log({
    prendas,
    idArticulo
  });
}

function modificarSubototales() {
  console.log('no sé qué hace esto');
}

function agregarDetalle(idarticulo, articulo, precio_venta, cantidad = 1) {
  let fila = document.createElement('tr'),
    celdas = getCeldas(idarticulo, articulo, precio_venta, cont, cantidad);
  fila.id = `fila${cont}`;
  fila.className = 'filas';
  celdas.forEach(celda => {
    $(fila).append(celda);
  })
  tabla.appendChild(fila);
  cont++;
  detalles = detalles + 1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  agregarDetalle(1, 'Camiseta', 99, 2);
  agregarDetalle(2, 'Pantalón', 230);
});
```

```css
#detalles {
  min-width: 300px;
}

#detalles .filas {
  height: 1em;
  min-width: 50px;
}

#detalles th {
  font-size: 0.95em
}

#detalles th,
#detalles td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td.numeric input {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7cfb5e92f4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="detalles">
  <thead>
    <th>Quitar</th>
    <th>Articulo</th>
    <th>Prenda</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Descuento</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th>Actualizar</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```